# How can I make syscalls directly?

Tags: unix, system-calls, bsd, openbsd

How can I execute syscalls directly? I'm using OpenBSD right now, the Unix platform.
I want to be able to call syscalls without the 'wrapper', as an example:
instead of `write(1, "hello!", 6)` I'd like to be able to type `syscall (4, 1, "hello!", 6)`.

Comment: https://man.openbsd.org/man2/syscall.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `syscall(2)` or `__syscall(2)`.

```c
#include <sys/syscall.h> /* syscall constants */
#include <unistd.h>      /* syscall() */

int
main(void)
{
    syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Hello\n", 7);
}
```